# skipping duplicate values in mysql while inserting to a target table

Tags: mysql

Hi i am trying to insert data into another table and i would like to skip duplicate record in the target table. I have used the following mysql query.

```
insert into adggtnz.`reg02_maininfo`(farmermobile,farmername,farmergender,origin) 
        select * from (SELECT mobile_no,name,sex,'EADD' FROM EADD.farmer)
        as tmp where not exists (select farmermobile from adggeth.`reg02_maininfo` where farmermobile = tmp.mobile_no)
```

The problem is that when there is a duplicate the query does not completely run how can i avoid the following error

```
16:09:03    insert into adggtnz.`reg02_maininfo`(farmermobile,farmername,farmergender,origin)          select * from (SELECT mobile_no,name,sex,'EADD' FROM EADD.farmer)         as tmp where not exists (select farmermobile from adggeth.`reg02_maininfo` where farmermobile = tmp.mobile_no) Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '0724961552' for key 'PRIMARY'    0.828 sec
```

Please help me modify my query

Comment: Learn about `INSERT IGNORE` and `ON DUPLICATE KEY`

Comment: You should tell us what you want to happen in this case.

Comment: i would like to skip if there is a duplicate from the target table

Comment: Really the easiest thing to do here would be to add a unique constraint on the column or columns which would define a record as being a duplicate.  Then, trying to insert would result in an error, but nothing would actually be inserted.

Comment: the unique key for the two tables is mobile number, i would like to ignore and skip the duplicate record being flagged by the insert query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid duplicate entries, you *never* EVER query first to see if a record exists. You place a `unique` constraint and use `INSERT IGNORE` or `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

The problem with first approach is that you can (and will) get false positives.

In your particular case, the fix is quite easy. You need to add `IGNORE` after `INSERT`. That will skip the record if duplicate and continue onto the next one.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO adggtnz.`reg02_maininfo`(farmermobile,farmername,farmergender,origin) 
SELECT mobile_no, name, sex, 'EADD' FROM EADD.farmer
```

Answer (score -1):

Get the select query which initially checks the farmer mobile number in reg02_maininfo and then insert into reg02_maininfo.

```
insert into adggtnz.`reg02_maininfo`(farmermobile,farmername,farmergender,origin) 
        SELECT mobile_no,name,sex,'EADD' FROM EADD.farmer where mobile_no not in 
        (select farmermobile from adggeth.`reg02_maininfo`)
```

Comment: This answer is completely wrong. Anyone coming here via google - bear in mind that in SQL - we don't check if record exists, we use constraints. That's the only proper way that's concurrency-safe.

Comment: The question is to insert the records which doesn't exists in another table witha key of mobile number. read the question once.  So we need to use a select statement provided the other table will retreive. In this query, initially read will happen and then write.

Comment: we can use Insert IGNORE, but this is not completely wrong

Comment: It is completely wrong. I wrote why. I can explain it further but I can't understand it for you. Your approach isn't safe against concurrency. It's also so much slower. This is the complete antipattern. I don't need detailed explanation on what happens, I'm very well aware how select and insert work.  Now, you can either learn something or argue with me for no reason, facts are facts no matter how much you wish they weren't.

Comment: I dnt want to argue with, but to understand things much clearer.  I accept the answer can be wrong with performance or something. But it will do the action as expected that is my point is. Hence its not completely wrong. if you don't mind you can explain much detail about the concurrency issue here. Just want to understand the things better as more senior you may be

Comment: The only way to ensure there are no duplicate records in a table is to place a `unique` constraint. While you select, a record might come in - because databases are systems made to be used by many at the same time. There is no prevention of duplicates. Your solution can let duplicates through or it can miss a record. Performing a select to verify existence is slower than using a unique index. It might look counter-intuitive but that's how it is. All the solutions that check if something exists via `select...` are incorrect. Constraints are there to enforce integrity, don't do it manually.

Comment: So your point is at the time of select, if an insert can come with a unique value.  But if we have the unique constraint, the above query can work as expected or it has any other pitfalls

Comment: If you have unique constraint, then you don't have to worry what happens to some other table mid-way or how many people / clients are performing inserts, you're stopping duplicates using MySQL's internal data structures. It's different when MySQL tells you "hey, you can't insert that, I already have it" opposed to asking MySQL for every record "hey, do you have this, can I insert it?".  You just insert, MySQL tells you "no, I got this" and then you tell MySQL "ok, fine, just move on to next record then".